# Main Activity not shown in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

I have an application in Android, I've changed the main Activity, and now nothing is showing up when I launch it. I don't know what could be wrong. Please help.

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
 />
<Button  
android:id="@+id/btnCrash"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/btnCrash"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="gdpTesis.client" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="gdpTesis.client.main.GdpTesisApplication">
    <activity android:name=".main.GdpTesisMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

The Activity

```
package gdpTesis.client.main;

import gdpTesis.client.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GdpTesisMainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, try Project -> Clean and let it rebuild.  Can you fire up logcat and see if there are any relevant messages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Main Activity not shown in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845411/main-activity-not-shown-in-android)

Comment: Please do not ask twice the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845411/main-activity-not-shown-in-android

Comment: I closed the original since this one has an answer.  In the future please just **edit** your posts instead of posting exact duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I CAN'T BELIEVE IT! I'm with the emulator, and I don't have an Android phone, so I expected after running the application, see it in the emulator screen, but it was locked, and it doesn't unlock by itself, so just unlocking it with the mouse...showed the activity. sorry! and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your naming conventions. The Activity package and name is

```
gdpTesis.client.main
GdpTesisMainActivity
```

The Manifest package and name is

```
gdpTesis.client
.main.GdpTesisMainActivity
```

I do not understand the need for

```
import gdtTesis.client.R
```

Consider:

Activity

```
package gdpTesis.client
class GdpTesis
```

Manifest

```
package gdpTesis.client
Activity name GdpTesis
```

and delete the Manifest Application name and import gdpTesis.client.R

Comment: The Activity is in the package named gdpTesis.client.main

The name in the manifest is because I'm using a class which extends Application.

And the
    import gdpTesis.client.R
is there because I commented out the code which uses the resources I have, but it should affect in this example.

Comment: I CAN'T BELIEVE IT!
I'm with the emulator, and I don't have an Android phone, so I expected after running the application, see it in the emulator screen, but it was locked, and it doesn't unlock by itself, so just unlocking it with the mouse...showed the activity. sorry! and thanks!